# iptables-restore v1.6.1: Can't use -i with OUTPUT

Tags: iptables, firewall

The line for the loopback interface is 
`-A OUTPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`
 
 but the error `iptables-restore v1.6.1: Can't use -i with OUTPUT` shows up

Answer (score 2):

A year late, but you probably wanted to write: *-o*

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you can not use `-i` with `OUTPUT`.

Because incoming packets aren't passing through from `OUTPUT` chains.